# Rails dynamically relation call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

everybody, i am using rails 4.0 and get some problems with using relations. I get model like this one:

```
class SingleMatch < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :question_1, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_1_id"
belongs_to :question_2, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_2_id"
belongs_to :question_3, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_3_id"
belongs_to :question_4, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_4_id"
belongs_to :question_5, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_5_id"
belongs_to :question_6, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_6_id"
belongs_to :question_7, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_7_id"
belongs_to :question_8, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_8_id"
belongs_to :question_9, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_9_id"
belongs_to :question_10, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_10_id"
belongs_to :question_11, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_11_id"
belongs_to :question_12, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_12_id"
belongs_to :question_13, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_13_id"
belongs_to :question_14, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_14_id"
belongs_to :question_15, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_15_id"
belongs_to :question_16, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_16_id"
belongs_to :question_17, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_17_id"
belongs_to :question_18, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_18_id"
belongs_to :question_19, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_19_id"
belongs_to :question_20, :class_name => Question, :foreign_key => "question_20_id"
belongs_to :user_1, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "user_1_id"
belongs_to :user_2, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "user_2_id"
belongs_to :winner, :class_name => User, :foreign_key => "winner_id"
```

then i get my object like:

```
@match = SingleMatch.find(params[:id])
```

Sometimes i need to call something like `@match.question_SOME_VARIABLE.question` (looping for all question-relation or similar). How can i do this ?

Comment: Wouldn't `has_many :questions` make more sense than all those numbered questions?

Comment: Seems like that, but for now it will destroy app-architecture at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(1..20).each do |i|
  @match.send("question_#{i}").question
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it's work perfectly. Where can i get documentation for it ?

Comment: @KyleKorver you don't have documentation for that, it's plain Ruby, not a Rails feature. You can eventually study more Ruby if you want to.

Comment: @KyleKorver Many people jump into learning Rails without having a solid understanding of Ruby. I highly recommend taking some time to learn the fundamentals of Ruby if you're serious about learning Rails.